# Post a Status in Facebook automatically Using Android

Tags: android, android-facebook

i used this code for posting status in facebook but it shows one text box and we have to write the status and click share but i want post a preset string, no need to type any thing just i want to pass one string and it should be posted as status. how can we do that. Please help me.

Post to Wall

```
     public void postToWall() {
    // post on user's wall.
    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {
      @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });
   }
```